# How can i make pieces a string on python?

Tags: python

How can i pieces string like 1403,1500 to x, y

```
def get_coord(self):
    try:
        coords = make_tuple(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[3]/div[4]').text)
        x_coord = 
        y_coord = 
    except:
         pass
```

Comment: Do you mean that `coords` is a string? Can you include the value of it in your question?

Comment: coords like be 1624 , 1212

Comment: It looks like selenium or something, add more tags...you're using more than python. Re-do the question to be more clear or someone will downvote.

Comment: So do you get what you want if you write: `x_coord, y_coord = coords`?

Comment: İm new in pyton and stackowerflow cuz maby my question isnt good sorry.

Comment: You should also print the output that you currently get for "coords" so that people can better understand how to answer the question

Answer (score 1):

In python you can unpack iterable objects like dicts, tuples, lists or strings. You can assign tuple values to variables like this:

```
coords = (1, 2)

x, y = coords 
print(x, y)
>>> 1, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have the following string

```py
coords = "1403,1500"
```

You want to extract the numbers as string then convert it to an integer.

```py
# Extract strings separated by ","
strings = coords.split(",")

# Convert to integer
x = int(strings[0])
# But it might fail, so you might want to handle the Exception
try:
    x = int(strings[0])
except ValueError:
    x = None  # Or whatever behavior you want


# Then all in one without handling the exception :
def extract_coord(coords: str) -> (int, int):
    return tuple(map(int, coords.split(",")))

x, y = extract_coord("123,456")
print(f"{x = } ; {y = }")
```